# Define variable before main

Tags: c, variables

I have question. If i define variable before main function like this:

```
#define N 10
```

then later in main i can't change this variable? Like this:

```
N=N+1;
```

And is there any way to make N bigger when its defined before main?

Comment: `N` is not a variable, it's just a preprocessor macro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a definition of a macro, not a global variable. Try this:

```
int i;

int main()
{
    i = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't use a Macro for this, you need a global variable for that.
FYI: Before the compilation, all Macros in your code gets replaced with their actual values wherever you have used that macro.
So if you define a macro, and then again try and modify that as a `Macro` then, it will consider that latest values of it.

What you think you have done is:

```
#define N (10)

N = N+1; //will this change N to 11? No, It wont!

int main()
{
  printf("\nI code rubbish");
  return 0;
}
```

What you can do is:

```
#define N (10)
//Some more macros
#define N (50)

int i = 10;

//Will i++ work here??? No, It wont!!!
int main(void)
{
  int k = 0;
  i++;
  k = N; //What is N here, 10 or 50? It is 50!
  printf("\nDo not learn to code, instead code to learn");
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this tells you what was wrong with your understanding